# How do I unstage a Moodle update

Tags: moodle

After logging in to my Moodle as admin, I clicked the link to update to the latest available Moodle version. However, the new version won't work with my hosting site's MySQL version. Simple enough, I just selected the cancel button. Nope. The cancel button does nothing. Additionally, whenever I log in as admin, I am redirected to the update confirmation page where I can't actually perform the update or cancel the action. The web hosting service restored a previous version from backup, but the very next time I logged in as admin I was right back at the same update page.

Is there any way to unstage/delete/remove the "I want to update my Moodle" flag/action/request/whatever from the Moodle database/data files?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Upgrading Moodle database from version 2.9.1+ (Build: 20150820) (2015051101.08) to 2.9.7 (Build: 20160711) (2015051107.00) mysql (5.5.5-10.0.28-MariaDB)
version 5.5.31 is required and you are running 5.5.5.10.0.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download the new version of Moodle, it overwrites the existing files. You need to move all your files from the Moodle code directory (NOT your Moodle data directory) into another directory, then download a clean copy of your previous version of Moodle (from Moodle.org) and place it in your original directory.

Once that is done, you will need to copy across your config.php file, along with any extra plugins you had installed.

After that, you should be able to log back into your site and it should be back to running as normal again.

Before you do any future upgrades, there is a compatibility check built into Moodle itself (I think it is somewhere under site admin > server, but I don't have a site open at the moment to check). It is worth looking at that before downloading the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks davosmith! It almost worked. "ERROR!!! The code you are using is OLDER than the version that made these databases!"

Comment: Hmm... sounds like it started the upgrade then. You *might* get away with editing the version number in the database table mdl_config, to match that in the main version.php, then going to the command line and running admin/cli/purge_caches.php

Comment: That my cause other problems though, as the database may end up inconsistent with the code.

Comment: Thanks! Before I try changing mdl_config, I think I've found a database and code set {local copy of (Build: 20150820) (2015051101.08) with plug-ins} that match and will work given the MySQL constraint. I need to working through other issues with my service provider first though.

Comment: I'm back up and running, thanks! Mental note to self: always make a backup of the Moodle code as well as the database and data.